# C++ Expected Primary Expression before '<<' Endl

Tags: c++

I keep getting an `expected primary-expression before '<<' token` compile error message when I try to compile the following code. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with endl; because when I remove '<< endl; ' from each part of the code it works fine

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int num1 = 0;

int funcNum1()
{
    cout << num1; << endl;
    int num1 = 2;
    cout << num1; << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << num1; << end1;
    int num1 = 1;
    funcNum1();
    cout << num1; << end1;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: cout<< num1 <<endl; 

You don't need a semicolon.

Comment: More strongly, you cannot have a semicolon. Statements cannot begin with `<<`.

Comment: Also, you have a number "1" instead of letter "l" in both of your "endl" in main function.

Answer (score 1):

You have made mistake in line `cout << num1; << end1;` change it to

```
cout << num1 << endl;
```

Chance this at both the places in your code.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from this code, after the `num1` you have semicolon. Remove this semicolon (you have also this problem in your function). Also, you have number 1 instead of l in `endl`. Fix this two error and it should work.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << num1; << end1;
    int num1 = 1;
    funcNum1();
    cout << num1; << end1;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In main() your syntax is off:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    cout << num1 << endl; // watch the semicolons, use "endl" not "end1"
    int num1 = 1;
    funcNum1();
    cout << num1 << endl; // watch the semicolons, use "endl" not "end1"
    system("PAUSE"); // system needs #include <stdlib.h>
    return 0;
}
```

You need the "stdlib.h" which is embedded in the "cstdlib" header to access the system() method: take a look at the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/)

Comment: @AviGinsburg, at what point in my post am I suggesting it isn't? cstdlib is a c++ wrapper that contains stdlib.h. This means that both would work equally in this example.